# Angular-Side nav bar, data-toggle collapses for all submenu

Tags: angular, navbar, togglebutton

I have created a side nav bar with sub menu. There are Chapters and in each chapters exercise. Chapters are drop down and even exercise inside chapters are drop down. But if I click any of the chapter all the chapters dropdown opens, if i click any of the chapter all the other chapters dopdown collapses.

```
<div class="wrapper sidbr">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <nav id="sidebar">
        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <li *ngFor="let Chap of mchapter" class="active">
                <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">{{Chap.Chapter}}</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                    <li *ngFor="let Les of Chap.Lesson">
                        <a href="#">{{Les}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here correct reference is not passing to submenu,try like this

```
<div class="wrapper sidbr">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <nav id="sidebar">
        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <li *ngFor="let Chap of mchapter" class="active">
                <a href="#homeSubmenu-{{Chap.Chapter}}" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">{{Chap.Chapter}}</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu-{{Chap.Chapter}}">
                    <li *ngFor="let Les of Chap.Lesson">
                        <a href="#">{{Les}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```